# Laravel migrate fresh specific migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I'm trying to migrate some database tables in my Laravel application. I'm using a third party library https://github.com/spatie/laravel-schedule-monitor which seems to break and requires re-migrating when upgrading. If I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` locally it'll work just fine, but amongst all of my other migrations I don't want to overwrite and dump the data in my other tables in a production environment.

I want to `migrate:fresh` a specific migration...

**UPDATE**

When trying to run the `refresh` command on a table, the below happens...

[image: monitors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another solution is to copy whats inside that migration and delete it and re-make that migration and paste data to that and run `php artisan migrate`

dont forget to dlete the table from phpmyadmin also

Comment: What exactly do you mean here?

Comment: If I try to delete the table, an error of: `MySQL said: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` occurs.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `php artisan migrate:refresh --path=`

example

```php
php artisan migrate:refresh --path=database/migrations/2020_09_02_000000_create_users_table.php
```

if you need rollback:

```php
php artisan migrate:rollback  --path=/database/migrations/2020_09_02_000000_create_users_table.php
```

Comment: Seems to work in that it skips over migrations, but when it hits my migration I just get `Base table or view already exists`, which `fresh` wouldn't typically do, it would just drop the table and re-migrate. Bizarelly the package I'm using was updated for Laravel 8 but doesn't play well with upgrading (thus why I want to re-migrate)

Comment: Yes, locally I had ran `php artisan migrate:fresh` initially and it had worked for running all of my migrations including the one I'm having issues with. Just tried that - with the addition of specifying a path, which works but then simply overwrites all of my data in my other tables if I proceed with a `php artisan migrate` as if I were adding new data in the future.

Comment: And when I run that, I get an error... `Base table or view already exists` because yes, it does exist, but I want it to drop and overwrite that table, which `fresh` would normally do, but removes data as per the above.

Comment: See the attached image in the description after running refresh

Comment: Tried rolling back, I can rollback but can't re-migrate the individual table. I cannot touch my users table otherwise they won't be able to log in.

Comment: try any demo table then because in my side it is working

Comment: as that table was not exist to cannot `refresh` so 1st you need to run `migrate` then you can try `refresh`

Comment: As previously discussed, I'm unable to run `php artisan migrate` as I receive an error.

Comment: For reference the above user's answer seemingly works initially, some errors in the core package itself though.

Comment: In what situation would one need `migrate:refresh` versus `migrate:rollback`?